# Call EditText's onClick event, when clicking inside of the layout it is in

Tags: java, android-studio, kotlin

I've written a custom layout made up from a Linear Layout, A TextView, an EditBox and another TextView. What I want to do is, when I click anywhere on the layout (it might be the edit box, or the textviews), to call the EditText's onClick event. I can get focus to it, by setting layout's onClickListener.

```
    val customLayout: LinearLayout = findViewById(R.id.custom_layout)
    customLayout.setOnClickListener {
            val editBox : EditBox = findViewById(R.id.edit_box)
            editBox.requestFocus()
        }
```

but i cannot seem to be able to get it to show the keyboard, and also the marker below the cursor. Is there any way to do this?

Answer (score 1):

You don't actually want its `OnClickListener`, you just want to set focus on the field and show the keyboard. The docs [have an example function](https://developer.android.com/training/keyboard-input/visibility#ShowOnDemand) you can use

```
fun showSoftKeyboard(view: View) {
    if (view.requestFocus()) {
        val imm = getSystemService(Context.INPUT_METHOD_SERVICE) as InputMethodManager
        imm.showSoftInput(view, InputMethodManager.SHOW_IMPLICIT)
    }
}
```

Just call that and pass your `editBox`